# How can I find out if a folder is UAC protected in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10, uac

I'm creating a program that allows me to synchronise directories in my computer (for instance to save my documents on a USB disk). By doing that I may have to copy files/create directories or even delete files and folders in UAC-protected folders (I'm saving all my python programs in *C:\Program Files\Python35*)

I can find out whether or not my script has admin privileges using the `ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin` function, and I'd can restart the program if it doesn't have administator rights by using `ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", "C:\...Python.exe, "C:\...My Program.py", None, 1)`. But I don't want to have to restart the program *every* time the user opens it without UAC-privileges, only if the folder handled require that privilege.

My current method is thying to place a folder in it using `os.mkdir`, capturing `PermissionError 13`, and deleting the directory if no exception occurs.

Is there any way I find out if a specific directory requires my program to have UAC-privileges in order copy files, create directories, and delete files/folders in it? Or can I correctly assume that everything out of the currents user's directory (returned by `os.environ["home"]`), and on the local hardrive (C:) requires UAC-privileges?

Comment: Check for permissions/ACL of the current user if they miss write access, check if admin group has full permissions and offer an elevation prompt if the admin group has all permissions